# why such an annoying binary search tree(bst) seg.fault error?

Tags: search, tree, insert, binary, traversal

> > **input no. of elements , elements of binary search tree , input elemt whoose subtree you want to display**

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

> > defn of struct node of bst

```
typedef struct node
{
int info;
struct node *right, *left;
}NODE;
```

> > insert fn , node at leaf

```
struct node* insertBst(struct node* root, int ele)
{

if(root == NULL)
{
    NODE* temp = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    temp -> info = ele;
    temp -> right = temp -> left = NULL;
    return root;
}

else if(ele > root -> info)
{
    root -> right = insertBst(root -> right, ele);
}

else if(ele < root -> info)
{
    root -> left = insertBst(root -> left, ele);
}


}
```

> > searching for the address of the ele

```
NODE* search(int ele, NODE* root)
{
if( root == NULL) return NULL;
if(ele > root -> info)
{
    return search(ele, root -> right); 
}

else if( ele < root -> info)
{
    return search(ele, root -> left);
}

else if(ele == root -> info) //ele found
{
    return root;
}

 }
```

> > displaying the made bst 
> >     using pre order : ROOT , LEFT, RIGHT

```
void preorder(NODE* root)
{
   if(root)
{
    printf("%d ", root -> info);
    preorder(root -> left);
    preorder(root -> right);
 }
}
```

> > driver where i call insert to create my bst, node whose subtree im >>displaying

```
int main()
{
int n, ele; //no. of elements in bst
NODE* root = NULL;
printf("no. of bst elements");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("elements to be inserted in bst");
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    scanf("%d", &ele);
    NODE* t = insertBst(root, ele);
}

printf("element whose subtree needs to be displayed");
scanf("%d", ele); //elements whose subtree is to be diplayed
NODE *temp;
temp = search(ele, root);
preorder(temp);
}
```

Comment: which line does it segfault?

Comment: @bunbun how do you find the line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the segfault is in the line:

`scanf("%d", ele);`

Where you should have passed the address of `ele` instead of it's value, like you did inside the `for` loop.

Also, your program won't work because function `insertBst` will never assign a root node as any time `if(root == NULL)` is true (always) you will allocate a node as you should, but you returns the same `root` which is still `NULL`. You probably meant to return `temp`.

Also, it's good practice to check `temp` (after the `malloc`) for `NULL` pointer before dereferencing it, as malloc can fail and return `NULL`, and dereferencing it will crash your program.